# Yii2 Ajax request to another file but not controller

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How can I make ajax request to a file which is not under `controllers` directory. In my case:

```
app/
   backend/
     componenets/
        DesieredClass|someMethod
```

Is it possible this way ? I tried to request it like a simple controller but without success ( also extend the class with the `yii\web\Controller` class to try this opiton )

Comment: can you explain a bit more why are you creating a separate class and extending it with `yii\web\Controller` if it already has actions defined as in Yii style why outside the `controllers` directory when it has to work the same way

Comment: i mean if you want to deny the direct access you can do it inside the `init()` or `beforeAction` of the controller, and place it in the controllers directory with all other controllers, just check if it is an AJAX request then allow otherwise throw an exception

Comment: apart from the above you have to name it as `WhateverController` to behave like a controller too

Comment: Just wanted to know is it possible.

Comment: Yeap .. Create a file under backend/web directory ... your url will be `baseurl/filename`